# What is the Latin translation for "showcase"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

I need the Latin translation for the word "showcase". I should use it in a blog, replacing the English word to indicate a collection of products or things to be shown to all the visitors.

Comment: Welcome!  This question doesn't show research effort, which is something we like to see, particularly in translation questions.  See [How can I ask a translation or homework question?](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/143/12).  Please provide the context in which you use the word, as well as the words you have discovered in your own searches (and why you are unsure about them).

Comment: It might well be that there is no Latin word or short expression for "showcase", but you have to explain it with several words. If that is indeed the case, the best translation probably depends on context. Can you add where you would like to use this expression? (Also, the suggestions @Nathaniel gave are good ones.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple options.

First, more plainly, you have *conlectio*, which simply means a gathering together. In rhetoric, though, it can also mean a summary of arguments (because a summary is a short collection of what was said before).

You could similarly use *conceptus*, but instead of the nifty summary definition, you get pregnancy instead. It still can mean simply a collection or gathering together.

You also have *conlatio*. Like *conlectio*, it can mean a gathering together of anything, but has the bonus of tending to mean ordered as well, which from there also extends to comparison of things.

I wouldn't go with any of these, but I am giving you them anyway.

To get *choicest* in that collection, you'll probably want to go with *electa* or *electio*. These have the added meaning of a collecting *the best* or *quality selections*.

If you want to be extra fancy, you could do what the ancients did when they gathered together the poems and use *anthologia* (from the Greek for "flower-gathering"), e.g. with the *Anthologia Graeca* (Greek Anthology) or *Anthologia Latina* (Latin Anthology), collections of short poems by both major and minor authors.

The Romans sometimes translated *anthologia* as *[florilegium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florilegium)*, which was the word used during the Medieval age for a collection of excerpted writings.

Comment: Wait—if you wouldn't go with *conlectio*, *conceptus*, or *conlatus*, then what would you suggest if "best selections," extra-fancy, or Medieval wasn't appropriate?

Comment: Ah, of course. I have a very good friend writing a book about display in natural history museums in the 19th century, so I went to a different place.

Comment: Way out of my depth here, but would just throw in *thesaurus* - treasure, treasury?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer They are now, but, fascinatingly, in the 19th century, especially early on, people basically just threw things in cases with little regard to what they were. It was like, here's a bunch of stuff you can look at, whatever, we don't care. (My friend might very well say that's completely the wrong way to look at it, but that's my impression after reading her work-in-progress.)